# Nielsen-Thurston decomposition from the product of Dehn twists

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

Given a closed surface of genus $g\geq 2$,  we know that the mapping class group $Mod(S)$ is generated by the Dehn twists. My question is

**Given an element as a product of Dehn twist, is it possible to write down the corresponding Nielsen-Thurston decomposition?**

Explicitly,  suppose $\phi\in Mod(S)$ such that $\phi=\prod_{i=1}^nT_{x_i}^{k_i}$ where $x_i$'s are simple closed curves, $T_{x_i}$ is the left Dehn twist about $x_i$ and $k_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Given this data, is it possible to write down the Nielsen-Thurston decomposition of $\phi.$

PS: Rivin's comment have helped me to find this [exact link](http://curver.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

Comment: There isn’t a simple recipe. Bell and Webb recently gave a polynomial-time algorithm to compute the Nielsen—Thurston type of a mapping class: https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09392v2 .

Comment: @HJRW Would you please write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t a simple recipe. Bell and Webb recently gave [a polynomial-time algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09392v2) to compute the Nielsen—Thurston type of a mapping class.  Their paper also contains a summary of previously known algorithms.

Comment: You can now also explore / play with these via Curver which includes a Python implementation of these algorithms. See http://curver.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 3):

Not only is it possible, it is implemented by Mark Bell and Saul Schleimer as [Twister.](https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgar/Maths/twister.html)

Comment: This is true, if you use Twister and Snappy together.  However, there is a cleaner way, which avoids hyperbolic three-manifolds.  Use Flipper, written as part of Mark Bell's thesis.  https://bitbucket.org/Mark_Bell/flipper

Comment: @SamNead Thanks! I have used it via SnapPy, so have a parochial view :)